# Extract values (not keys) from a List<Map<String,String>>, and flatten it to a List<String>

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

How would I extract the values (not keys) from a `List<Map<String,String>>`, and flatten it to a `List<String>`?

i.e. tried the following but doesn't work.

```
List<Map<String,String>> mapList = .... ;

List<String> valueList = mapList.stream()
                                .map(o -> o.getValue())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'd like to filter the result by a given key as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean :

```
List<String> valueList = mapList.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.values().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit**

> What if I want to specify a key e.g. I have "id" and "firstName", but
>   only want "firstName"

In this case you can use `filter` after the `flatmap` like so :

```
List<String> valueList = mapList.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.entrySet().stream())
        .filter (e -> e.getKey().equals("firstName"))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList ());
```

Comment: Thanks, just realised that this gets all the values, and I only need one set. What if I want to specify a key e.g. I have "id" and "firstName", but only want "firstName".

Comment: add a filter
```
List<String> valueList = mapList.stream()
  .flatMap( i -> i.entrySet ().stream ()
                .filter (entry->entry.getKey ().equals ("firstName"))
                .map (entry->entry.getValue ()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList ());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.flatMap`:

```
List<Map<String,String>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, String> mapOne = new HashMap<>();
mapOne.put("1", "one");
mapOne.put("2", "two");

Map<String, String> mapTwo = new HashMap<>();
mapTwo.put("3", "three");
mapTwo.put("4", "four");

mapList.add(mapOne);
mapList.add(mapTwo);

List<String> allValues = mapList.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // [one, two, three, four]
```

Comment: What if I want to specify a key e.g. I have "id" and "firstName", but only want "firstName". Right now this grabs all of the values (sorry mistake on my part...)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
    List<String> valueList = mapList.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("KEY"))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The object o you are trying to map to o.getValue() is of type Map (which does not have a function getValue()), not Map.Entry (which would have such a function). What you can is get a Collection of the values with the function o.values().

You can then get a Stream from that collection, and flatten the resulting Stream of Streams like this:

```
List<String> valueList = mapList.stream()
                         .map(o -> o.values().stream())
                         .flatMap(Function.identity())
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```